# Parse cloud page data into Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, ssjs

I have data on cloud page in this format. It is neither a JSON nor XML that i can easily parse.

I basically retrieved this with a HTTP GET and write it on cloud page.

My goal is to load this data into a data extension. I have this as string  obj but parsing it as a JSON is not possible.

Can anyone help with this solution on this?

```javascript
<script runat="server">
     Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
    var response = HTTP.Get("xxxxxxxxxx");
    var obj =  Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content);
    
  var strobj  = Stringify(obj);
  </script>
```

This is the data on the cloud page. I need to send this in Data extension?

```
var GIC_annual = {'12\x2d17 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.250', '249999.99':'4.250', '999999.99':'4.250', '9999999.99':'4.250'},
'18\x2d18 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.750', '249999.99':'4.750', '999999.99':'4.750', '9999999.99':'4.750'},
'19\x2d23 MTHS' : {'99999.99':'4.750', '249999.99':'4.750', '999999.99':'4.750', '9999999.99':'4.750'},
'24\x2d35 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.700', '249999.99':'4.700', '999999.99':'4.700', '9999999.99':'4.700'},
'36\x2d47 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.500', '249999.99':'4.500', '999999.99':'4.500', '9999999.99':'4.500'},
'48\x2d59 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.450', '249999.99':'4.450', '999999.99':'4.450', '9999999.99':'4.450'},
'60\x2d71 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.500', '249999.99':'4.500', '999999.99':'4.500', '9999999.99':'4.500'},
'72\x2d83 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.600', '249999.99':'4.600', '999999.99':'4.600', '9999999.99':'4.600'},
'84\x2d119 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.700', '249999.99':'4.700', '999999.99':'4.700', '9999999.99':'4.700'},
'120\x2d120 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.800', '249999.99':'4.800', '999999.99':'4.800', '9999999.99':'4.800'}};
```

Comment: Please update your question with the details about the target Data Extension.

Comment: What's the connection between `strObj` and `GIC_annual`?

Comment: GIC_annual is posted on our website in the same format as shown above. i was thinking of treating it as a JSON and than use a for loop to load it into a DE. but this a weird format.  how can i read this data and load it into a DE?

Comment: What's the connection between strObj and GIC_annual? I was trying to parse it as string  into a array and loop it to retrieve the data. but that also looks not possible in the format it is available

Comment: And what do you intend to store in the DE for this object?

Comment: I want to retrieve these rates for journey

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to fix your JSON so it'll parse, if you intend do anything with it.

You can do that with a regex replace:

```javascript
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">

Platform.Load("core","1");
var debug = true;

var GIC_annual_str = 
"{'12\x2d17 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.250', '249999.99':'4.250', '999999.99':'4.250', '9999999.99':'4.250'},'18\x2d18 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.750', '249999.99':'4.750', '999999.99':'4.750', '9999999.99':'4.750'},'19\x2d23 MTHS' : {'99999.99':'4.750', '249999.99':'4.750', '999999.99':'4.750', '9999999.99':'4.750'},'24\x2d35 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.700', '249999.99':'4.700', '999999.99':'4.700', '9999999.99':'4.700'},'36\x2d47 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.500', '249999.99':'4.500', '999999.99':'4.500', '9999999.99':'4.500'},'48\x2d59 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.450', '249999.99':'4.450', '999999.99':'4.450', '9999999.99':'4.450'},'60\x2d71 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.500', '249999.99':'4.500', '999999.99':'4.500', '9999999.99':'4.500'},'72\x2d83 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.600', '249999.99':'4.600', '999999.99':'4.600', '9999999.99':'4.600'},'84\x2d119 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.700', '249999.99':'4.700', '999999.99':'4.700', '9999999.99':'4.700'},'120\x2d120 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.800', '249999.99':'4.800', '999999.99':'4.800', '9999999.99':'4.800'}}"

var regex = new RegExp(/'/, "g");
var GIC_annual = GIC_annual_str.replace(regex,'"')
var GIC_annual_obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(GIC_annual);

if (debug) {
  Write("<br><br>GIC_annual_obj: " + Stringify(GIC_annual_obj));
  Write("<br><br>GIC_annual_obj.length: " + GIC_annual_obj.length);
}

for (key in GIC_annual_obj) {
  Write("<br>key: " + key);
}


} catch (e) {

  if (debug) {
   Write("<br><br>e: " + Stringify(e));
  }

}
</script>
```

**Output**

```
GIC_annual_obj: {"12-17 MTH":{"99999.99":"4.250","249999.99":"4.250","999999.99":"4.250","9999999.99":"4.250"},"18-18 MTH":{"99999.99":"4.750","249999.99":"4.750","999999.99":"4.750","9999999.99":"4.750"},"19-23 MTHS":{"99999.99":"4.750","249999.99":"4.750","999999.99":"4.750","9999999.99":"4.750"},"24-35 MTH":{"99999.99":"4.700","249999.99":"4.700","999999.99":"4.700","9999999.99":"4.700"},"36-47 MTH":{"99999.99":"4.500","249999.99":"4.500","999999.99":"4.500","9999999.99":"4.500"},"48-59 MTH":{"99999.99":"4.450","249999.99":"4.450","999999.99":"4.450","9999999.99":"4.450"},"60-71 MTH":{"99999.99":"4.500","249999.99":"4.500","999999.99":"4.500","9999999.99":"4.500"},"72-83 MTH":{"99999.99":"4.600","249999.99":"4.600","999999.99":"4.600","9999999.99":"4.600"},"84-119 MTH":{"99999.99":"4.700","249999.99":"4.700","999999.99":"4.700","9999999.99":"4.700"},"120-120 MTH":{"99999.99":"4.800","249999.99":"4.800","999999.99":"4.800","9999999.99":"4.800"}}

GIC_annual_obj.length: 9
key: 12-17 MTH
key: 18-18 MTH
key: 19-23 MTHS
key: 24-35 MTH
key: 36-47 MTH
key: 48-59 MTH
key: 60-71 MTH
key: 72-83 MTH
key: 84-119 MTH
key: 120-120 MTH
```

I'd suggest using something like [jsonpathfinder.com](https://jsonpathfinder.com) to inspect the keys for pulling out the values.

[image: jsonpathfinder example]

Comment: Can you add  Regex that will remove anything like   / var [a-z] =/ and replaed by empty space